# gulp-replace only replacing text in some files in a folder

Tags: gulp, gulp-replace

I am using gulp replace to replace a string with the version number from my package.json file as follows:

```
gulp.task('replace', ['uglify','process-html','copy-release'], function () {
    return gulp.src([releaseFolder + '/**/*.html',releaseFolder + '/app.js'])
            .pipe( debug({title:"replace files"}))
           .pipe(replace( "__applicationVersionNumber__", packageJson.version ))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(releaseFolder));
});
```

This works but of the 6 files in releaseFolder/tempaltes/*.html only 5 of them are replaced:

[image: grunt output showing 5 files in the templates folder processed]

[image: folder contents of templates folder showing 6 files]

This is replacing the text on the files in place. I.e. they are saved back to the same place when the replace is done. If I set the output location as different they are all replaced but they are already in the location I need them to be in.

Why is the last file missed?

Thanks

My entire gulpFile is here:
https://github.com/Roaders/YouTubeCommentator/blob/3808036d7ce1fa84e035bc01cc765c5dd7a1e008/gulpfile.js

Comment: Best guess: the file doesn't exist yet when the `replace` task runs. Probably because of one of the other three tasks it depends on.

Comment: yes, the copy-release task copies the files into this location but the replace task doesn't start until the copy task has finished. Do I need to add a delay or something?

Comment: No, you need to make sure you don't have any concurrency/async completion mistakes in your gulpfile.

Comment: OK, I have added a link to my gulpfile. Can you see any issues there?
Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all your tasks are incorrectly signalling [async completion](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support). For each task you should do **one** of the following two:

- If you're using a stream, return it from the task function
- If you're not using a stream, call the callback function

Since you seem to be using streams in all of your tasks, you can just get rid of the callbacks.

For example your `copy-release` task should look like this:

```
gulp.task('copy-release', ['clean'], function () {
  return gulp.src([
      './templates/**/*.html',
      './lib/**/*.js',
      './assets/**/*.*',
      './css/**/*.css'
    ], {base: './'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(releaseFolder));
});
```

Comment: many thanks, that was exactly what the issue was. Only started using gulp today so it's all very new.